# Cant properly finish a python project

Tags: python, python-3.x

During my university studies i was assinged to **Create a program that counts the digits(0-9) from a string as well as other characters(not defined[probably all]). Your program will output a 11character string,that will count how many numbers it came across in the input. The first character would be the number of ZEROS python read in the string,the second one will do the same job but will show how many ONES it saw and ETC. The 11th character will be how many NON numbers are inside my string. If a number exceeds the 9time you should mark it with an ASTERISK. For example. INPUT=01710 OUTPUT=22000001000 ** For now have gone as far as here

```
lista=[]
thesi=0
def ins(lista_v1):
    for i in range (len(lista_v1)):
        thesi=thesi+1
    if lista_v1[i]>9:
        lista_v1.pop(i)
        lista_v1.insert(thesi,"*")
    for i in range (len(lista_v1_)):
        if lista[i]!="0123456789":
            different=different+1
    print ("{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}").format(lista[0],lista[1],lista[2],lista[3],lista[4],lista[5],lista[6],lista[7],lista[8],lista[9])

zero_count=0
one_count=0
two_count=0
three_count=0
four_count=0
five_count=0
six_count=0
seven_count=0
eight_count=0
nine_count=0
different=0
thesi=0

user_data=input()
while user_data!="END" and "end":
    if "0" in user_data==True:
        zero_count=zero_count+1
        lista.append(zero_count)
    else:
        lista.append(0)
    if "1" in user_data==True:
        one_count=one_count+1
        lista.append(one_count)
    else:
        lista.append(0)
    if "2" in user_data==True:
        two_count=two_count+1
        lista.append(two_count)
    else:
        lista.append(0)

    if "3" in user_data==True:
        three_count=three_count+1
        lista.append(three_count)
    else:
            lista.append(0)

    if "4" in user_data==True:
        four_count=four_count+1
        lista.append(four_count)
    else:
            lista.append(0)
    if "5" in user_data==True:
        five_count=five_count+1
        lista.append(five_count)
    else:
            lista.append(0)
    if "6" in user_data==True:
        six_count=six_count+1
        lista.append(six_count)
    else:
            lista.append(0)
    if "7" in user_data==True:
        seven_count=seven_count+1
        lista.append(seven_count)
    else:
            lista.append(0)
    if "8" in user_data==True:
        eight_count=eight_count+1
        lista.append(eight_count)
    else:
            lista.append(0)
    if "9" in user_data==True:
        nine_count=nine_count+1
        lista.append(nine_count)
    else:
            lista.append(0)
    ins(lista)
```

I am editing the print part for now inside the DEF. Any suggestion would be appreciated!. I am really sorry for the link.I am having too much trouble inserting python code with this editor. I will try again later. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a few comments that might be helpful:

I think it would be a good idea to set the size of `lista` once at the beginning of your program, and not use lista.append(). You know from the start what size it needs to be: one for each digit 0-9, and one for anything else, for a total of 11 items in the list. You also need to "initialize" each item in `lista` to zero. There are a few ways to do both things, but one straightforward way is:

```
lista = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Then each time the code finds, for example, a "5" in the input string, the program need to add one to the item in `lista` used for counting "5"s. You could use `lista[5]`. For example:

```
lista[5] = lista[5] + 1
```

Or, you can be a power programmer and use this shortcut:

```
lista[5] += 1
```

Using `lista` like this means that you don't have to use `zero_count`, `one_count`, etc.

I also think you need to repair this statement:

```
while user_data!="END" and "end":
```

This is a place where you have to be very clear and use the format that the computer expects. I think what is meant is (in English), 'while user_data is not equal to "END" and not equal to "end"...'

But that's not how the computer will understand it. When the computer reads the "and", it divides things up into whatever came before it, and whatever comes after it. (The same thing happens with "or".) Once the computer figures out those results, it uses the "and" to combine them. For "and", both what came before and what comes after have to be True for the combination to be True.

In this case, What came before it is `user_data != "END"`. That's fine, and does what I think you expect. But what comes after the "and" is just `"end"`. In the Python language, the computer will read that and translate it to True.

In Python, there are keywords True and False, which have the obvious meanings. Also, 0 (the number zero) is translated to False; 1 (the number one) is translated to True. There's more: Python generally treats completely empty things (lists, etc.) as False, and non-empty things as True. That's why it translates "end" into True. It's a non-empty thing.

For now, I'd suggest you stick to using logical statements like you have, but remember to make each part stand correctly by itself.

I'll check back, in case you post questions in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed post!  Its been sometime and i have redone everything from the scratch.I have been doing this like all day long. This is what i have done https://repl.it/repls/WaterloggedBetterDisk .I did not saw your post unfortunately but i will  look that in detail tomorrow! I am going for sleep,i will check back when i wake up! Thanks !!!!!!!!

Comment: Hello! I have this version without the while and the user asked input https://repl.it/@TimothyMcGee/PYTHON-MXATZ Works fine.This is my while version which i am currently editing. https://repl.it/@TimothyMcGee/TESTING-WHILE?language=python3 You can see the edit live as well